# How do I make check appear in an edit form?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

Basically I have a form that I start out with. On that form is the option to select a checkbox and once I click submit on that form, the information is read into a database and the condition on whether the checkbox has been selected now displays a '0' or '1' in the database.

Now I have an edit form. I choose the row I want to edit and my edit form gets populated with what is in the row. The only thing that doesn't show up, is whether that row was 'checked' on the first form. I want the checkbox to be marked if the user checked the checkbox on the first form and visversa.

Sorry if this sounds like a terrible explination.

Code for the first form:

```
<form method="post" action="processForm.php">

    Name: <input type="text" name="names" required = "required"><br>

    Activate: <input type="checkbox" name="activateBox"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Create Users"><br>
</form>
```

And code for edit form:

```
<form method="post" action="editForm.php">

    ID: <input type="text" readonly name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><br><br>
    First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $row['firstName']; ?>"><br><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" value="<?php echo $row['lastName']; ?>"><br><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>"><br><br>
    Activate: <input type="checkbox" name="activateBox" value="<?php echo $row['activated']; ?>"><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Update"><br>

</form>
```

I tried doing this but it did nothing. I'm sure I'm missing something pretty simple but I can't figure out what.

```
if (isset($_POST['activateBox'])) {
    echo 'checked="checked"';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `checked` attribute of the `<input type="checkbox">` tag should work. Most likely, when you loaded the edit form, it was an HTTP `GET` request, rather than a `POST`, so the `$_POST['activateBox']` was empty.

In any case, reading the current state on an edit form from the client seems wrong. Shouldn't the current state come from the database?

Try this:

```
Activate: <input type="checkbox" name="activateBox"<?php if ($row['activated']) echo " checked"; ?>>
```

Comment: any idea on how could I get around that then?

Comment: I tried that and something similar before but still no luck. Also did you get rid of value= on purpose?

Comment: I find the `value` attribute in `<input type="checkbox">` doesn't provide much utility in practice. When the checkbox is checked, the browser submits the default value and when the checkbox is not checked, the browser doesn't submit anything for the checkbox. So in practice, your server side form handler can simply check if `isset($_POST['activateBox'])`. The actual value isn't needed.

Comment: Yes you did...Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Activate: 
<input type="checkbox" name="activateBox"
<?php 
if($row['activated']==1){
  echo ' value="1" checked'; 
}else{
 echo ' value="0";
?>
<br><br>
```

Comment: I lied, my mistake. Didn't realize you had value gone as well. @Asaph had it first though. Thanks!!

Comment: like I said, @Asaph had the same basic thing and he had it first. I just didn't get rid of value= because I thought I needed it.

Comment: Plus, Asaph "explained" it. A better answer I feel, even if it was put in first.